# Building an HTML Page on back-end side, and returning entire file in php variable

Tags: php, html

So this is my issue. I'm working on a school project and I need some help.
I am trying to figure out how I can let PHP run a .php file, and save the resulting generated html file into a variable which can be rendered by another page.

This is the way I thought was best.

-**Index.php** ( calls a function inside a loader.php file)

-**Loader.php** ( Searches if the module exists and requests a page render )

-**PageRender.php** ( Open the file, execute any scripts inside the file and return the resulting html page )

-**Page.php** ( A PHP file that has a function inside it that gets a set of user values from the database )

The only problem is that when I use the `file_get_contents` function, It just strips all PHP code and returns only the HTML inside the page.

Example:

page.php

```
<DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>A title<title>
  <head>
  <body>
   <h1> Set of user results: </h1>
   <?php
    echo "some user value";
   ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

And the pageRender.php

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('page.php'); ?>
```

But this will only output this:

> Set of user results:

Is it possible to let a .php file run on the server, and return the generated HTML? Or any other way that could accomplish my goal?

Comment: php eval function may help you http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_eval.asp

Comment: The output of file_get_contents is the result of the parsed php script that outputs html.  Which is exactly the goal you want accomplished no?

Comment: Does your output not also include `some user value` within the html?

Comment: @anshuVersatile Ah this is a step in the right direction. Unfortunately I can't use this function since there is going to be a mix of HTML and PHP that's returned by the PageRender.php file. Using this function immediately returns the arror that I cannot use HTML characters in this function.

Comment: @Progrock Not exactly. There are PHP Scripts in the file that i want to request. But those scripts need to be executed before the file is returned.

Comment: Perhaps there is some confusion here.  When calling `file_get_contents($url)`, give it the full web address i.e.`http://example.com/foo`.  To trigger Php's parsing on the server side.

Comment: @Pragrock Oh I did not know that that would work. I'm Dutch so sometimes it's hard to understand some things in English haha. Let me give that a go and see if I can get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Pragrock It worked. Can you submit this as an answer? Then I can accept it and close this question.